# Bootstrap - Responsive navbar works on index page but no other page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Pretty much says my issue in the title. The responsive nav works fine for the index page, but on other pages, it doesn't. It still collapses, but nothing happens when you click on the dropdown icon.

My nav code is:

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem1"><a href="index.html"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem2"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem3"><a href="gallery.html"><strong>GALLERY</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem4"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem5"><a href="aboutus.html"><strong>ABOUT US</strong></a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical navitem6"></li>
                            <li class="navbar_link navitem7"><a href="contact.html"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you included the necessary JavaScript? Both jQuery and the Bootstrap library are required for it to work. I pasted your coded as-is and it worked just fine.